# Avoid CSS override when new html loaded in div

Tags: html, css, kendo-grid

**Introduction**

I am working on kendo grids for user email inbox functionality. Emails are loading in grid perfectly, no problem, i can feel so much satisfaction in my mind. I can view detail of each email.

`Problem` starts on the detailed view when third party rich-content emails load in detail div and overrides the CSS of the website. Its easier to imagine what the main website might look like.

> Research:I have made research to avoid this override behavior but it
>   seems there is no other solution than `specificity`. I cannot change
>   css allover to avoid override.

**Edit**

> Another option was to load newly loaded html(email) in iframe if one
>   can resole iframe issues.

If someone already faced this type of issue, please do help. Any kind of help or reference will be appreciated.

Thanks for your time.

Comment: are you loading third party web content in your website or div ? you can load those data in iframe to avoid css conflicts

Comment: A class selector beats any number of element selectors. So if you wrap your site with the class "my app". Then use sass preferably to update you whole css under my app

Comment: @DhavalPankhaniya thanks for the comments, third party emails loading in email functionality, those rich emails causing problem.

Comment: @Wimanicesir thanks for the tip, i will look into it.

Comment: @DhavalPankhaniya please post it as answer. Although i already had iframes in my mind.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using any third party content like html or email you should use iframe to avoid css conflicts that could distort ui and [Cross-site scripting (XSS)](https://excess-xss.com/) that could break your page or steal your data.

Answer (score 1):

This is the reason why most email clients either use iframes, or prohibit style tags within the email's content.

For example Gmail sanitizes the `<style></style>` tags and find the matching `elements` and appends the `styling inline`.

Outlook renders the content inside of an iframe but most removes of the styling tags.

From a practical point of view I would say it's much easier to output your content like Google. This does mean you'll have use/create a serverside pre-processor to properly sanitize the email contents and add them as inline styling to the appropriate elements.